# Wifi Adapter issue

Tags: wifi

I am trying to get my wifi adapter running being a newbie I am stuck, I have however searched internet a lot and found nothing useful. So, Here's the situation.

I have purchased this wifi adapter
http://www.amazon.in/Adapter-Raspberry-Wireless-Dongle-adapter/dp/B0134C7DRS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1454423075&sr=8-1&keywords=wi+fi+raspberry+pi

It is a ralink device

**It is being listed in lsusb as:**

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.MT7601U Wireless Adapter

**I think its being listed in *lsmod* too** as it shows

**mt7601u** in the list

Now **ifconfig-a** test is negative since there isn't any **wlan0** listed
there's just

**eth0** and **lo**

Kindly help me out I am really frustated now.
I've run

**apt-get update**

**apt-get rpi-update**

**apt-get upgrade**

but still nothing.

**EDIT**
I am powering the pi with a 2.1A power adapter so I think its unlikely to be a power issue. And dmesg is as follows

```
 157.457955] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[  157.924137] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[  157.924163] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
```

Comment: I use this USB adapter just fine.  My lsusb shows what you have, my lsmod shows mt7601u.  However, my "ifconfig" shows "wlan0".  I'd suggest rebooting your Pi and posting an attachment containing the output of dmesg.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) shows how to setup WiFi, or repair your setup if you have changed something. This won't help if the dongle is not detected.

As it is shown by `lsmod` and `lsusb` is appears OK. The other possibilities are inadequate power. WiFi devices typically require a lot of current. Try with a better PSU or a powered hub.

`dmesg -T` will show what is happening on boot.

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: @SalimShamim This shows `usb` but you need to see what is happening on `wlan`

Comment: The thing is when I run ifconfig, there are only two things showing there eth0 and lo, you have any idea about this as to why it is happening.